# After form reset, js checkValidity() no longer functions correctly

Tags: javascript, html, validation, internet-explorer

IE11 issue here, works in other browsers (go figure).

I have a form with a set of radio buttons.

The radio buttons have the `required` attribute

When I load the page and run the `checkValidity()` function on the form, it returns `false`. **This is correct.**

I check a radio button. I run the `checkValidity()` function on the form, it returns `true`. **This is correct.**

When I click the reset input button it clears my radio button selection, however, when I run the  `checkValidity()` function on the form, it returns `true`. **This is incorrect.**

This is a violation of the HTML specification. (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#value-sanitization-algorithm)

This behavior is only happening in IE, any thoughts on a fix for this?

I have added a code snippet below with an example of my problem.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="foo">

  <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="This" required> This</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="That" required> That</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="other" required> Other  </label>

  <input type="reset" value="Reset Button">
  <input type="button" value="JS Reset Form" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
  <input type="button" value="Is Valid?" onClick="alert(this.form.checkValidity())" />
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 10/11 has only [partial support of validity check](https://caniuse.com/#search=checkvalidity) and reset does not trigger validation in IE11 (probably bug). You have to do it manually:

```js
function resetForm(form) {
 form.reset();
 // re-set any input value, it forces IE to re-validate form
 var input = form.querySelector('input, select');
 input.value = input.value;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="foo">

  <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="This" required> This</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="That" required> That</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="other" required> Other  </label>

  <input type="button" value="JS Reset Form" onClick="resetForm(this.form)" />
  <input type="button" value="Is Valid?" onClick="alert(this.form.checkValidity())" />
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on bigless's reply, I think you could create a JavaScript validate function to validate the form, thus, you could use the reset type button and "this.form.reset()",
code as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validityForm(form) {
        var input = form.querySelector('input, select');
        input.value = input.value;
        alert(form.checkValidity());
    }
</script>
<form id="foo">

    <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="This" required> This</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="That" required> That</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="xx" value="other" required> Other  </label>

    <input type="reset" value="Reset Button">
    <input type="button" value="JS Reset Form" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
    <input type="button" value="Is Valid?" onClick="validityForm(this.form)" />
</form>
```